# PageKite: HTTP Error 400

Tags: localhost, iis-express

I try to use Pagekite for localhost tunneling. My web application uses some port for HTTP and other one for SSL on localhost and it runs on IIS-Express. My kite page was displayed as a default local host page when I run PageKite without specified port and that's good. But I receive Bad request - Invalid Hostname when I try to specify my ports.
My service_on lines on PageKite.cfg looks like:

```
service_on  = http:@kitename    : localhost:my_Http_Port_Here    : @kitesecret
service_on  = raw-22:@kitename  : localhost:my_SSL_Port_Here  : @kitesecret
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't do that using Pagekite but I have found other localhost tunneling app - ngrok. This here is a command line for ngrok that works:  ngrok http -host-header=localhost [my_port]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this option could have helped:

`$ pagekite.py 80 NAME.pagekite.me +rewritehost=project.dev`

Source: http://pagekite.net/wiki/Howto/WebDevelopment/#hosthdr

Comment: Im sorry its not clear to me how i apply this. can this be set in the cfg file?